# Alert Generation Tools/Solutions- Open source

Tags: alerts

I am looking for any open source tools that allows to monitor business data and based on threashold/rules setup, it can identify alerts and call custom API to store in a data base or directly store in a custom DB.

These alerts from custom db will be used to display alerts in a an existing website where users are engaged .

thanks..

I read about promethus and i am not sure if thats for this kind of requirement or is it mainly for IT operations.